# How to make "Run As" dialog's dropdown list to show all users?

Tags: windows-xp, runas, multiple-users

In my Windows XP Pro, I have my main user named as `admin` that is a member of *Administrators* group. I created two *limited* users (`power1` and `power2`) then assigned them as members of *Power Users* group.

When loged in usig `admin` and I right-clicked a program/shortcut to open the *Run As* dialog, the dialog's dropdown list only shows two users: `Administrator` and `admin`. The remaining two users: `power1` and `power2` is not listed.

While I can still type `power1` or `power2` manually to use them without problem, I want the dropdown list to show all users (all 4 of them). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "User name" dropdown of the system "Run As" dialog consists of the individual users (not groups) in  the groups `Administrators`.

As an alternate solution, try [ShellRunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx) from the Microsoft SysInternals Team

1. Install the program by running `ShellRunAs /reg`.
2. Right-click any program (or shortcut), and click "Run as different user..."
3. Modify the user dropdown using the following system dialog:
   `rundll32 keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr`

Comment: Doesn't work. Even by creating a new user with *limited* account type won't make it listed in the *Run As* user selection. Note: *limited* account type is a member of `Users` group.

Comment: Update: The *Run As* dialog user selection list seems only shows users that are member of `Administrators` group. Any lower level groups like `Backup Operators`, `Network Configuration Operators`, `Replicator`, etc. won't do.

Comment: @Jay, see edited answer (use ShellRunAs)

Comment: I was hoping not to use a custom *Run As* launcher, but I'll accept it. Now the question is, how to exclude (not delete) dialup entries from *Run As* selection list? i.e.: show only Windows-login type users. I use a saved dialup password to automate dialup connection, so it must not be deleted.